# Add product to cart programatically is not updating totals

Tags: php, magento

I want to add product to cart from a external file

Here is my code

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');

Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();

$productId = 123;
$productQuantity = 1;
$productModel = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product');
$productObj = $productModel->load($productId);

if (!$quoteObj) {
    $quoteObj = new Mage_Sales_Model_Quote();
}

$store_id = 1;
$storeObj = $quoteObj->getStore()->load($store_id);
$quoteObj->setStore($storeObj);

$quoteItem = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->setProduct($productObj);
$quoteItem->setQuote($quoteObj);
$quoteItem->setQty($productQuantity);
$quoteItem->setStoreId($store_id);

$quoteObj->addItem($quoteItem);
$quoteObj->setStoreId($store_id);
$quoteObj->collectTotals();
$quoteObj->setCustomerId(null);
$quoteObj->save();
$quoteId = $quoteObj->entity_id;

$quote1 = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStoreId($store_id)->load($quoteId);
print_r($quote1->getData());
```

Printed info.

```
    [grand_total] => 0
    [base_grand_total] => 0
    [subtotal] => 0
    [base_subtotal] => 0
    [subtotal_with_discount] => 0
    [base_subtotal_with_discount] => 0
```

Here what i found the it is not updating the totals.

why what is wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 0):

You are saving the quote but I am not sure it is enough. You should try saving the cart. And try to `collectTotals` before printing `getData` :

```
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$quote = $cart->getQuote();

Your code .... 

$cart->save();

$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStoreId($store_id)->load($quoteId);
$quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals();
print_r($quote->getData());
```

Comment: Maybe this is nothing but you don't set your `$quoteObj`, you are always creating a new one. See line 4 above.

Comment: yes, this script will run only if i don't have any products in my cart

Comment: Ok another possible solution. Try to update your quote using this code `$quoteObj->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals();`

Comment: still i have same issue

Comment: Where did you put this collectTotals thing ?